# Determine the distribution of $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Let $X$ be continuously uniformly distributed on $(0, 1)$. Let $\lambda> 0$ and $Y = -\frac{1}{\lambda}\ln (1 - X)$.

Determine the distribution of $Y$. Make a note of the intermediate steps.

That means that we have to calculate the distribution function of $Y$, i.e. $F_Y(y)$, right?

We have the following :

$$\begin{align*}F_Y(y)&=P(Y\leq y)\\&=P\left (-\frac{1}{\lambda}\ln (1 - X)\leq y\right )\\&=P\left (-\ln (1 - X)\leq \lambda y\right )\\&=P\left (\ln (1 - X)\geq -\lambda y\right )\\ & =P\left (1 - X\geq e^{-\lambda y}\right )\\&=P\left ( X\leq 1-e^{-\lambda y}\right )\\&=F_X(1-e^{-\lambda y})\end{align*} $$

Is that correct and complete?

Comment: Looks good so far but you are missing one final step. You also know what $F_X$ is, so what does $F_X(1-e^{-\lambda y})$ equal?

Comment: Does it hold that $$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } x<0 \\ x & \text{ if } x\in (0,1) \\ 1 & \text{ if } x>1\end{cases}$$ ? @angryavian

Comment: Then $$F_X(1-e^{-\lambda y})=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } 1-e^{-\lambda y}<0 \\ 1-e^{-\lambda y} & \text{ if } 1-e^{-\lambda y}\in (0,1) \\ 1 & \text{ if } 1-e^{-\lambda y}>1\end{cases}=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } 1<e^{-\lambda y} \\ 1-e^{-\lambda y} & \text{ if } 0<1-e^{-\lambda y}<1 \\ 1 & \text{ if } e^{-\lambda y}<0 \text{ rejected}\end{cases}=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } e^{\lambda y}<1 \\ 1-e^{-\lambda y} & \text{ if } -1<-e^{-\lambda y}<0 \end{cases}=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } \lambda y<0 \\ 1-e^{-\lambda y} & \text{ if } 0<e^{-\lambda y}<1 \end{cases}$$ @angryavian

Comment: And so $$F_X(1-e^{-\lambda y)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if }  y<0 \\ 1-e^{-\lambda y} & \text{ if } 0<e^{-\lambda y}<1 \end{cases}$$ Is that correct so far?@angryavian

Comment: Yes, but look at $e^{-\lambda y}<1$ what does that mean for $y$?

Comment: From that we get $e^{\lambda y}>1 \Rightarrow \lambda y>0\Rightarrow y>0$, right? @Bayesianguy

Comment: Yes, and that is the exponential distribution as you said... just be carefull you miss something at $(0,1)$, one of those must be closed.

Comment: Although we  have that $X$ is continuously uniformly distributed on the open $(0,1)$ we should have one of these closed at $Y$ ? @Bayesianguy

Comment: Well in that case $x \leq 0$ and $x \geq 1$.

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle{F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ falls } x\leq 0 \\ x & \text{ falls } x\in (0,1) \\ 1 & \text{ falls } x\geq 1\end{cases}}$ and so $$F_X(1-e^{-\lambda y})=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ falls } 1-e^{-\lambda y}\leq 0 \\ 1-e^{-\lambda y} & \text{ falls } 1-e^{-\lambda y}\in (0,1) \\ 1 & \text{ falls } 1-e^{-\lambda y}\geq 1\end{cases}$$ ? @Bayesianguy

Comment: Almost there, it is OK but look what you got in the last step and that's it

Comment: Inthe last step  we get $$F_Y(y)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{ if }  y\leq 0 \\ 1-e^{-\lambda y} & \text{ if }  y>0 \end{cases}$$ right? @Bayesianguy

Comment: That's it! You got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X \sim U(0,1)$, then $F_X(x)=x$ for $0 < x \leq 1$. Then,

$$F_Y(y)=F_X(1-e^{-\lambda y})=1-e^{-\lambda y}.$$

What does that mean? $Y \sim ??$

Comment: So dowe check only the case $0<x\leq 1$ ? Do we get then what I wrote at the comments below my question?

Comment: Looks like something from the exponential family.

Comment: So is $Y$ distributed exponentially?

Comment: Exactly!! Yes you are right.

Comment: So do we have $Y\sim \text{Exp} (\lambda ) $ ? @Bayesianguy

Comment: Yes, you are right. Only check my comment below

Comment: Thank you for your help!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

A separate approach.

We want to transform $x\mapsto -\frac{1}{\lambda}\ln(1-x)$ .

Then you have the $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{\lambda(1-x)}>0$ for $x\in(0,1)$.

So you have $f_{Y}(y)=|\frac{dx}{dy}|f_{X}(x)=\lambda(1-x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda y}\,\,,y>0$.

So the pdf of $Y$ is that of a $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ variate ..

So cdf of $Y$ is $F_{Y}(y)=\begin{cases}1-e^{-\lambda y} \, ,y\geq 0\\ 0 \,,\text{elsewhere}\end{cases} $

This is what is known as the Jacobian Transformation.

In general :-

If you want to transform $X$ to $Y(X)$.

Then the pdf $f_{Y}(y)=|\frac{dx}{dy}|f_{X}(x)$ . ( In the RHS you just replace x with the expression of x in terms of $y$, i,e the inverse transformation).

This can be generalized to higher dimensions.

If you want to transform $(X_{1},X_{2},...X_{n})$ to $(U_{1},U_{2},..,U_{n})$ where $U_{i}$'s are functions of $(X_{1},X_{2},...X_{n})$
Then $$f(u_{1},u_{2},...u_{n})=|\frac{\partial(x_{1},x_{2},..x_{n})}{\partial(u_{1},u_{2},..,u_{n})}|f(x_{1},x_{2}...,x_{n})$$

Comment: I guess with inverses being at time only local?

Comment: @MSIS what are you trying to ask?